# Kalman filter: state estimate

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation, time-series, kalman-filter

Assume we have a linear state-space model:
$$
z_{k} = Hx_{k} + v_{k}\\
x_{k} = F x_{k-1} + w_{k}
$$

If I understand correctly, having observations $z_{0}, \dots, z_{k}$, in filtering problem the goal is to get the estimate $\hat{x}_{k|k} $ of $E[x_{k}|z_{k}, \dots, z_{0}]$.

The question: why do we call $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ the **state** estimate if state is itself random?

In wiki, it is even more confusing:

In what follows, the notation $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{n|m}$ represents the estimate of $x$ at time $n$ given observations up to and including at time $m \leq n$.

Answer (score 2):

Each measurement is associated with a certain time index and this then also fixes the associated estimate of the state with respect to an index. For example $\hat{x}_{k|k} = E[x_{k}|z_{k}, \dots, z_{0}]$ is a different problem compared to $\hat{x}_{k+1|k} = E[x_{k+1}|z_{k}, \dots, z_{0}]$. Namely, in that case the measurement $z_{k+1}$ is not used, so during that time step one can only predict. For example if $w_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,W)$ then the expected value of the prediction would yield $\hat{x}_{k+1|k} = F\,\hat{x}_{k|k}$.

Also note that the state itself is a stochastic process, which does not have to be completely "random" since it can be modeled by $x_{k} = F\,x_{k-1} + w_{k}$. Only if $F=0$ would the state inherit all the stochastic properties from $w_k$.

Comment: "the state itself is a stochastic process, which is does not have to be completely "random"" - I am totally confused... In a bayesian framework one can estimate the random parameters... but in the description of Kalman procedure one does not write it explicitely

Comment: @ABK How do you define "random"? Namely, each $v_k$ and $w_k$ are usually a sample from a certain distribution, independent of time. And frequently is assumed that this distribution is zero mean Gaussian white noise.

Comment: Dear @Kwin van der Veen, random means non-constant, i.e. having a certain distribution. This is a simple explanation.

Comment: @ABK as a couter example would you consider $x_k=k$ random? Also, it would be a possibility that $w_k=0$ for all $k$, in which case $x_k$ would be deterministic if you would know the initial conditions.

Comment: of course you can think of it as a degenerate case of random variable! According to definition of estimator of parameter, the parameter is not a random variable.

Comment: @ABK Maybe your confusion comes from that the true state $x_k$ can change over time. Indeed, if the state where constant you could consider the Kalman filter as a parameter estimation algorithm (like recursive least squares) in which case the first index $k$ of $\hat{x}_{k|m}$ would not have much meaning. However, for Kalman filters the state can evolve over time. Think for example about the temperature in a room or the position of a car. So the thing that you are trying to estimate is not time independent, so you also have to define at what time instant you want to estimate the state.

Answer (score -1):

The notation $\hat{ x}_{n|m}$ means $E(x_n|z_m,\cdots,z_0)$. When $m=n$, estimating $x_t$ is the filtering problem, when $m>n$, it is the prediction problem, and it is the smoothing problem for the cases where $n<m$.